# unpivot calculated columns value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT  

P.EmployeeId,
(P.Amount*1)*T.RegularHours as RegularEarnings
,(P.Amount*1.5)*T.OTHours as OvertimeEarnings 
,(P.Amount*2)*T.DOTHours as DoubleOvertimeEarnings
,((P.Amount*1)*T.RegularHours)+((P.Amount*1.5)*T.OTHours )+((P.Amount*2)*T.DOTHours)+((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(AMOUNT),0) FROM EmployeeEarning WHERE EmployeeId=T.EmployeeId)) as GrossPay
FROM TimeSheet  as T
INNER JOIN PayInformation as P ON T.EmployeeId=P.EmployeeId
```

above is my select statement which returns me earnings in column format . I want to `unpivot` my resulted table so that each `employeeId` have two columns one is earning type and second one is amount of earning .

I already done with simple unpivote

```
select unpvt.car_id, unpvt.attribute, unpvt.value
from @cars c
unpivot ( 
 value 
 for attribute in (Make, Model, Color)
) unpvt
```

but now stuck as i have to unpivot tables values calculated in select statement .

I have attempt something more and here is my latest code

```
SELECT unpvt.EmployeeId, unpvt.Earning, unpvt.Amount
FROM 
(SELECT    
P.EmployeeId,
(P.Amount*1)*T.RegularHours as RegularEarnings
,(P.Amount*1.5)*T.OTHours as OvertimeEarnings 
,(P.Amount*2)*T.DOTHours as DoubleOvertimeEarnings
,((P.Amount*1)*T.RegularHours)+((P.Amount*1.5)*T.OTHours )+((P.Amount*2)*T.DOTHours)+((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(AMOUNT),0) FROM EmployeeEarning WHERE EmployeeId=T.EmployeeId)) as GrossPay
FROM TimeSheet  as T
INNER JOIN PayInformation as P ON T.EmployeeId=P.EmployeeId )as c
unpivot ( 
Amount
for Earning in (RegularEarnings,OvertimeEarnings,DoubleOvertimeEarnings)
)unpvt
```

and now i am getting error

**`The type of column "OvertimeEarnings" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.`**

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly convert the columns to float or decimal? If Amount and RegularHours are both int, Regularearnings will be int while OvertimeEarnings will be float because of the multiplication with 1.5

Comment: All columns are in decimal(18,2)